# Why my post (and get) in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I start PHP some days ago and I start use it with form but it doesn't seem to work after I put value in my form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo implode(" ; ", $_GET);
        if (isset($_GET['test'])){
            echo $_GET['test'];
        }
    ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="test" placeholder="type smt">
        <input type="submit" value="OK" name="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should work. you sure PHP is actually processing the file? just make a simple PHP page that is empty except `<? phpinfo() ?>` and see if it prints anything.

Comment: When you add a `var_dump($_GET, $_POST);` to your source code, what output do you get before you send the form and after you send the form (with data)?

Comment: Let's start with the basics. Are you running this page on an actual web server, or are you just opening it in your browser?

Comment: @dqhendricks : It prit a lot of thing in an inline text

Comment: @Progman : It print "array(0) { } array(0) { }" and nothing append when I put value and send the form

Comment: @j08691 : I've installer PHP and start the five server extension on VS Code, but the connection to a database work perfectly (I use XAMMP as PHP Server)

Answer (score 1):

I change my PHP server from XAMPP to Easy-PHP and it works perfectly, I think something just gone wrong with the installation of XAMPP.